# How to create multiple object and store in one object and pass to backend process?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create an object using ajax and pass to backend when ajax call.

When i get the data from my backend it is in array, where i need to do like test['testone'] to get my data.

```
$('.checking').each(function() {
        test = {'testone' : 'test', 'testtwo' : { 'item1' : 1, 'item2' : 2 }};
 });

//when get data from my backend
$test['testone'] will get test
//how to get data in this way
$test->testone will get the result same as $test['testone']
```

Is there anyway i can do like test->testone instead of test['testone'] to get my data?

I am using javascript to push my data into empty variable and pass it through ajax.

Comment: you could pass it as `application/json` instead of  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and parse it with `json_decode` with second parameter `false`

Comment: what is the problem in doing `test['testone'] `?

Comment: I'm not able to understand your problem, could you add a context and add a little bit more (such as your ajax call, a backend response sample, what you aim for, etc..) ?

Comment: How do you decode request body in the backend?

Comment: The question, is there a way to make test['one'] as test->one where i need to pass it from my ajax. There's nothing wrong with test['one'] but i want to know about what should i do if i want to get the data in this form test->one instead of test['one']. My ajax always pass as array so i cant use the pointer.